# How to display No Data Available Message in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Can we display a message using highcharts, when the data set does not return any data?
For example : "No Data Available"

Comment: I'm using `chart.showLoading('No data to display');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been added per the [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1065633-display-no-data-to-display) entry.

Answer (score 22):

It is now supported in Highcharts since v3.0.8

You need to load the [no-data](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#noData) module and then, you can specify a custom message through the [lang.noData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.noData) option:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({lang: {noData: "Your custom message"}});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a little workaround to solve this problem. Basically I'm overlaying a div containing the message "No Data to Display".

```
.noChartData {
     display: hidden;         
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 99;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: normal;
     color: #CCC;
}

<div class="noChartData">No Data to Display</div>
```

When the page loads I'm using JQuery to find the position of the chart then offsetting the "No Data" div and revealing it accordingly.

```
var chartPosition = $("#myChart").position();
$(".noChartData").css("left", chartPosition.left + 400);
$(".noChartData").css("top", chartPosition.top + 150);
```

You'll need to vary the offsets accordingly depending on the size of your chart. I am using an AJAX call to pull in the series and category data so I know just before I bind the chart whether or not to reveal the floating "No Data" div.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example:

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({lang: {noData: "Your custom message"}})
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: []
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 250px"></div>
```

Hope this helps someone