# No data found message in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Below is the highcharts code I am using with dynamic values $fprgreen, $fprblue and $fprdrkorange.

```
             $('#seo-perform-fpr').highcharts({

                        exporting: {
                             enabled: false
                        },
                        credits: {
                             enabled: false
                        },
                        title: false,
                        chart: {
                             plotBackgroundColor: null,
                             plotBorderWidth: null,
                             plotShadow: false,
                             type: 'pie'
                        },

                        tooltip: {
                             pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                             pie: {
                                  allowPointSelect: true,
                                  cursor: 'pointer',
                                  dataLabels: {
                                       enabled: false
                                  },
                                  showInLegend: false
                             }
                        },
                        series: [{
                             colorByPoint: true,

                             data: [{
                                  name: 'High',
                                  color: '#8bc43f',
                                  y: <?php echo $fprgreen;?>
                             }, {
                                  name: 'Steady',
                                  y: <?php echo $fprblue;?>,
                                  // sliced: true,
                                  // selected: true,
                                  color: '#01A9F4',
                             }, {
                                  name: 'Underperforming',
                                  y: <?php echo $fprdrkorange;?>,
                                  color: '#f57c00',
                             }, ]
                        }]
                   });
```

If the values of $fprgreen, $fprblue and $fprdrkorange are 0, I need to show "No data found" message on the place of pie chart.

Comment: Why not check those values before creating the chart, and only build the chart if the values meet your criteria? Or use the `loading` options: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/loading

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008625/how-to-display-no-data-available-message-in-highcharts