# R Highcharter: How to show No Data to Display message?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have created a dynamic Highchart in R Shiny App. I want to display a customized message when there is no data to display the charts.

In Highchart API, there is setOptions where you can display the customized message. Something similar is mentioned in this question: [How to display No Data Available Message in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008625/how-to-display-no-data-available-message-in-highcharts).

But I haven't found anything similar in Highcharter.

Any solutions?

Comment: Hi. I was trying, but I am not sure how to load this module into Highcharter. You can ask the author on Highcharter repo: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `renderHighcharter` function, you can put something like this:

```
shiny::validate(
            need((nrow(DataSet()) != 0), "No data available based on your selection")
          )
```

You can have as many validate functions that you need and make them as complicated as you need to help the user troubleshoot.